# libGdx not correctly displaying the color of a selected pixel

Tags: java, libgdx, desktop-application, pixel

I am trying to have my program recognize when it has clicked a continent.
To do this, I have used:

```
new Color(texture.getTextureData().consumePixmap().getPixel(x, y));
```

with x and y corresponding to the mouse's respective coordinates.

This is the image being used:
[image]

and this is what it looks like after I have clicked three different locations on the map:
[image]

Getting the arbg values of each point clicked on the map, the results are as follows:

- On the continent: 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
- To the west of the continent: 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
- To the north-west of the continent: 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0

From these results, the first and second are indistinguishable although they focus on different colors entirely. Furthermore, going north suddenly renders all arbg 0?

Does anyone have any idea why this is occuring? Is there a work-around to get the color of a pixel?
Thank you.

PS: This project is for desktop.
PPS: When checking for all alpha values for each pixel, this is what I get when I display them. It seems like the image is flipped?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I noticed your data is arbg instead of rgba. Could you make this clear?

How are you getting the data from Color object? The problem might be there.

I tried your code, It gave me an error. You needed to call prepare function.

```
texture.getTextureData().prepare;  
Color color = new Color(texture.getTextureData().consumePixmap().getPixel(x, y));
System.out.println(color.toString());
```

Code above seems to work. Just make sure you are trying to find the color on the right texture.

Also make sure you have imported the the correct Color class. (java.awt.Color is not the correct one)

**EDIT:** Silly me. I just remembered. Coordinate system in the libGDX is different than the coordinate system of the input (if I remember correctly), try this:

```
mouse.y = ScreenHeight - mouse.y;
```

Rendering is done on the 4th area of the coordinate system. While the input is in the 1st. So the Y axis is reversed. Here is a link about coordinate system that might help you understand better.

[libgdx coordinate system differences between rendering and touch input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514152/libgdx-coordinate-system-differences-between-rendering-and-touch-input)

To test this, draw something on the location of the touch. See if it is drawing at the same place you touched.

Comment: I did call prepare beforehand, but I don't think that's where the issue lies. I've added to my original post - the image seems flipped when checking arbg values.