# libgdx system origin not match on device and on emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, libgdx

LibGDX on my emulator shows origin, (0,0), at bottom left, but my device is at top left. Please help!

I modified the tutorial of two screens as my program and uses `font.draw()` to draw font at screen as menu. The drawing of fonts works fine, but the `touchup + touchDown` event that implements `InputProcessor` gives different system origin on device and emulator.

> emulator: Android 4.0.3 level 15
>
> device: Samsung Galaxy Nexus, android 4.2.1.

Should I switch from LibGDX to OpenGL ES 2?

Thank you very much!

Best Regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the Coordinate System in LibGDX (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708379/changing-the-coordinate-system-in-libgdx-java)

Comment: Actually it isn't. What he asks is different, check my answer. @BennX

Answer (score 3):

The touchup an touchdown events in **InputProcessor** give you the actual pixel you clicked, with the device screen units. Starting at the top left corner. You should always [unproject](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html#unproject%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3%29) your touchs to camera coordinates.

- Create a Vector3:

  ```
  Vector3 touchPoint = new Vector3();
  ```
- Unproject it using your camera:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button){
      cam.unproject(touchPoint.set(screenX, screenY, 0));
  ```
- And then use the touchPoint.x and touchPoint.y as your touch coordinates.