# Y axis down and fliped scene2d elements

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d, coordinate-systems, scene2d

In my app I use orthographic projection with reversed y axis, as suggested in [Changing the Coordinate System in LibGDX (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708379/changing-the-coordinate-system-in-libgdx-java)

It works fine - I know how to draw fonts, textures and so on. 
Recently I wanted to try out scene2d component and it turned out all actors/widgets are flipped vertically (work fine when I disable reversing of y axis). Is there a way to force scene2d widgets (and e.g. dialogs) to work properly with reversed y axis?

greetings
Bartek

Comment: Scene2d.ui does not support a flipped Y axis.