# Android Studio libgdx setToOrtho(ydown = true) does not work

Tags: android, libgdx

i´m currently working on a Android game with the library libgdx. Currently I m facing a problem, where the xy-coordinate system is flipt.

I did some research and found that if you use a OrthographicCamera you can change the y coordinate so its no longer flipt.

Code:

```
public class Game extends ApplicationAdapter {
Miner miner;
SpriteBatch batch;
TouchManager touchManager;
OrthographicCamera camera;

public void create(){
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.setToOrtho(true, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    miner = new Miner(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("miner_lv1.png")), 0, 0, 200, 200);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    touchManager = new TouchManager();
}

public void render(){
    //update
    camera.update();
    touchManager.update(camera);
    miner.update();

    //drawing
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(Gdx.gl20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    miner.render(batch);
    batch.end();
}

public void dispose()
{
    batch.dispose();
    miner.dispose();
}
```

}

Miner:

```
public class Miner extends Entity {
public Miner(Texture texture, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    super(texture, x, y, width, height);
}

@Override
public void update() {
    sprite.setX(x);
    sprite.setY(y);
}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    sprite.draw(batch);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    texture.dispose();
}
```

}

The output is as following:
[Ouptut of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gaKx.png)

**My question is how do i change the coordinate system that x = 0 and y = 0 is in the top left corner.**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the Coordinate System in LibGDX (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708379/changing-the-coordinate-system-in-libgdx-java)

Comment: No, i got the information about the ydown from there, but it doesnt work as you can see.

Comment: it if is in the top left corner by default.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the camera until you call `batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);`.